# Bulk grant privileges to multiple tables at once in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I am able to grant multiple privileges (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) to multiple Users/Roles to one single Table each time on an Enterprise Geodatabase from ArcCatalog 10.1.

That's done by Manage -> Privileges... for each Table.

Now that I have got a large number of Tables/Views, just wondering whether there's a way/tool/PyScript of bulk granting privileges to all the Tables/Views at once.

Comment: If using Oracle it is not a recommend route but you can write a few lines of SQL to do the GRANT on TABLES (and loop each table) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187886/grant-select-on-all-tables-owned-by-specific-user

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Maybe I can write a script to grant privileges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [Change Privileges](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n3000000) geoporcessing tool.

This tool:

> Establishes or changes user access privileges to the input ArcSDE
>   datasets, stand-alone feature classes, or tables.

You could write a python script and grant rights over several tables/featureclasses for several user at once.

Comment: @alextc: Glad to help you out!

Comment: geonet post solved with SQL request (ArcSDESQLExecute) and Change Privileges

https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/how-to-duplicate-privileges-from-one-sde-feature/td-p/701768

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I wrote for PostgreSQL geodatabases that grants permissions on all user tables and views. It ignores the SDE i*, sde_log*, n_* (network), nd_* (network dataset), t_* (topology) tables but includes the version tables a* and d*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mgis_gdb_grant_all(dbrole text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE schemaname text;
DECLARE usertbls text;
BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg((concat(tbllist.table_schema, '.', tbllist.table_name)), ', ') INTO usertbls
    FROM (SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables
          WHERE table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'
          AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'public', 'sde')
          AND table_name NOT LIKE 'sde\_log%'
          AND table_name !~ E'^i\\d+'
          ORDER BY table_schema, table_name) As tbllist;

    EXECUTE format('GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE %s TO %I', usertbls, dbrole);
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.mgis_gdb_grant_all(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.mgis_gdb_grant_all(text) TO postgres;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION public.mgis_gdb_grant_all(text) FROM public;
```